# Temporarily disable indexes before updating whole table

Tags: postgresql, index, update, amazon-rds, pg-restore

For testing purposes I periodically restore production backup into a new database (AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance) with `pg_restore`. In the new database I run SQL queries that anonymize sensitive data. However, a query like below updates over 20M records in a table that has ~10 indexes (created during `pg_restore`).

```
UPDATE users SET email = users.id || '@example.com',
phone_number = NULL;
```

This takes a few hours on current setup.

To speed things up, I wanted to disable the table's indexes just for running the `update` and then enable them again and reindex the table. How can I do this? Any other ways to speed up this `UPDATE`?

Notes:

1. I've tried

   ```
   UPDATE pg_index
   SET indisready=false
   WHERE indrelid = (
       SELECT oid
       FROM pg_class
       WHERE relname='users'
   );
   ```

but got the error below.

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_index
```

Apparently you can't do this as superuser in AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance.

2. Dropping the indexes and then creating them again wouldn't be convenient, because I would have to know what columns they cover in advance. Ideally I would have a command that store existing index configuration in some temporary variable and then recreate them again using this info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you restore the data, use `pg_restore --section=pre-data --section=data`.  This will leave off the indexes.

Then run the UPDATEs you want to, then run `pg_restore --section=post-data`